# Fourier Coefficients

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform, frequency, spectroscopy, signal-processing

Suppose i've a two voice samples v1 and v2. Comparatively voice v1 is louder than the v2. If both the voice is spoken by the same person.(Spoken normally as he speaks)

Is it good to state the following facts for my assumption.

1. Plot of the Fourier coefficients differs between voice sample v1 and v2.
2. Frequency component will remain same for those voice samples. (Because spoken by same person.)

My intuition behind assumption 1 is that, the Fourier coefficients are nothing but the amplitude of each sine waves(or cosine waves in Cosine transform) so loudness depends on the amplitude of the each waves(but their phase do matters). Is my interpretation, assumption correct.

Comment: What do you mean by 'frequency component'? If you're asking whether the coefficients will just all be rescaled by the same constant, then the answer is *yes*. The Fourier transform is *linear*, so if $f(t)\to\lambda f(t)$ for some $f(t)=\sum_k f_k e^{2 \pi i k t}$ then $f_k \to \lambda f_k$.

Comment: The only difference may be that in the effort to increase volume, the frequencies change slightly due to differences in tension etc. in the trachea.  I am not sure by how much the frequencies would change, but I think the FFT of a yell versus normal conversation-level talking are slightly different, not just in power/amplitude.